# BuildConfig is defined multiple times, Gradle Test Build error

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, dex

```
 Type com.nikolam.nsdkelper.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /storage/Users/Volks/Desktop/Android-2020/NsdKelper/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/nikolam/nsdkelper/BuildConfig.dex, /storage/Users/Volks/Desktop/Android-2020/NsdKelper/nsdkelper/build/.transforms/6fff326acaa87110e65737aff5d0e0cd/classes/classes.dex
```

`./gradlew test build`  outputs this
I have an App Module that implements my LibraryModule and thats it

These are the recommended fixes

```
This error typically occurs due to one of the following circumstances:
A binary dependency includes a library that your app also includes as a direct dependency. For example, your app declares a direct dependency on Library A and Library B, but Library A already includes Library B in its binary.
        To resolve this issue, remove Library B as a direct dependency.
    Your app has a local binary dependency and a remote binary dependency on the same library.
        To resolve this issue, remove one of the binary dependencies.
```

These are the dependencies for the two build gradles of the library and the app.

```
dependencies {
///LIBRARY
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

///APP
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(":nsdkelper")

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


}
```

Apps whole build.gradle https://hastebin.com/dehedobica.php 
Libraries whole build.gradle https://hastebin.com/omahuqutuc.nginx

I can remove the direct dependency and use JITPACK.io but I'd like to keep it local for development, I tried updating the dependencies, gradle version and downgrading versions but nothing seemed to work. I also deleted some dependencies but that didn't help either. I invalidated cache and similar common fixes but no luck.

I tried removing the dependencies from the App module and just implementing the Library(NsdKelper) but it doesn't work like the way I think it does. My way of thinking is

A implements project B which means that A will check B's dependencies and use those. But that doesnt seem to be the case here. Removing the dependencies from my App Module gives me errors of missing libraries. Or I am I misunderstanding something

Answer (score 3):

They had the same Package ID, renaming the package on one of the modules solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in android/build.gradle solved the problem for me:

```
project.ext {
    excludeAppGlideModule = true
}
```